# Kubernetes postgres replication with pgpool

Tags: postgresql, authentication, kubernetes, database-replication, pgpool

Trying to deploy postgres in kubernetes (https://github.com/paunin/PostDock/tree/master/k8s/example2-single-statefulset),

1. Used pgpool-II(2 replicas) along with 1 postgres-master pod & 2 slave pods.

```
kubectl get pods -n postgres
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
psql-db-pgpool-8****c-7**k             1/1     Running   0          35d
psql-db-pgpool-8****c-m**5             1/1     Running   0          35d
psql-db-node-0                         1/1     Running   0          35d
psql-db-node-1                         1/1     Running   0          35d
psql-db-node-2                         1/1     Running   0          20h
```

2. Created a user "test" from the master postgres db with postgres user.
3. When trying to connect from within the pods(node-0), the authentication is successful, with user "test".

```
root@postgres-db-node-0:/# psql -h localhost postgres -U test
psql (11.4 (Debian 11.4-1.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> \l
```

1. When trying to connect with NodePort IP & NodePort of the kubernetes cluster, the new user "test" fails authentication with **pool_passwd file does not contain an entry for "test"**

```
psql -h NODE_IP -U test -d postgres --port NODE_PORT
psql: FATAL:  md5 authentication failed
DETAIL:  pool_passwd file does not contain an entry for "test"
```

5. Logged in to the pgpool-II pod to find out

```
root@psql-db-pgpool-8****c-7**k:/# cat /usr/local/etc/pool_passwd
user1:md5****422f
replica_user:md5****3
```

The new user "test" created at the database is not reflected at the pgpool. Does it work this way, to create & update pgpool everytime a new user is created? Or am I missing something for this user update.

Answer (score 1):

The postgres example You deployed uses secret object to store user and password credentials. And this is the recommended way of managing sensitive data in 
kubernetes deployments.

There are following [instructions](https://github.com/paunin/PostDock/blob/master/k8s/README.md#example-for-k8s) in this example:

- Create namespace by  `kubectl create -f ./namespace/`
- Create configs:  `kubectl create -f ./configs/`
- Create volumes  `kubectl create -f ./volumes/`
- Create services  `kubectl create -f ./services/`
- Create nodes  `kubectl create -f ./nodes/`
- Create pgpool  `kubectl create -f ./pgpool/`

If You followed them in correct order, the `mysystem-secret` secret object is created when `kubectl create -f ./configs/` is called from [`configs/secret.yml`](https://github.com/paunin/PostDock/blob/master/k8s/example2-single-statefulset/configs/secret.yml).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  namespace: mysystem
  name: mysystem-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  app.db.user: d2lkZQ== #wide
  app.db.password: cGFzcw== #pass
  app.db.cluster.replication.user: cmVwbGljYV91c2Vy #replica_user
  app.db.cluster.replication.password: cmVwbGljYV9wYXNz #replica_pass
  app.db.pool.users: d2lkZTpwYXNz #wide:pass
  app.db.pool.pcp.user: cGNwX3VzZXI= #pcp_user
  app.db.pool.pcp.password: cGNwX3Bhc3M= #pcp_pass
```

*Note that the comments next to each encoded password is decoded password so in production setting it should be avoided.*

Then the user and password credentials from `mysystem-secret` are used in `kubectl create -f ./nodes/` and `kubectl create -f ./pgpool/` as environmental values that are in all replicas and can be used to connect to Database.

```
...
            - name: "POSTGRES_USER"
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysystem-secret
                  key: app.db.user
            - name: "POSTGRES_PASSWORD"
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysystem-secret
                  key: app.db.password
...
```

If You want to use Your own user and password You need to modify the `configs/secret.yml` file and replace passwords you wish to modify with base64 encoded passwords.

You can easily encode any password to base64 with following command:

```
echo -n 'admin' | base64
YWRtaW4=
echo -n '1f2d1e2e67df' | base64
MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
```

---

Update:

To add additional users that would work with pgpool after cluster deployment you can use tool [postgres-operator](https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator). Users added manually via exec to pod and then created locally would not be propagated to other nodes.

Follow [these](https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/latest/installation/install-pgo-client/) instructions to install Postgres Operator (pgo client) and configure it to work with kubernetes.

Comment: I am clear with all of this & have completed it in a proper way. The issue I'm facing is, I created a new db_user 'test' from within the postgres database. Tried to connect db with this user "psql -h localhost postgres -U test. This logs me in from within the db_pod.
When I try the same user to login via pg-pool "psql -h NODE_IP -U test -d postgres --port NODE_PORT". It is not letting me login. 
Does it mean, user_list of pgpool & db_users are completely different? Can't I use the db_users to login via pgpool?